# how to add external users to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 site and I got the users from an active directory, now I have to add external users but I can't add these to the active directory of the company, how can I do it? I have imagined two ways:

1. create a local active directory in my machine, add users and import them from central administration (I don't know if this is possible)
2. add form web authentication and create the users in it.

is there any other way? how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form based authentication is the way to go, you should use ASP.NET Membership Provider (which uses SQL Server) for external users..

A handy starting point for using Form Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013 is the codeplex project by Visigo: [SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/)